# Android:Where is exactly Android 1.6 SDK download?

Tags: android

I want install Android version 1.6 SDK. I already have Android development setup with Eclipse and Android 1.5 SDK.
Wherever i search in Google to download Android 1.6 SDK, it finally goes to link: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

This link has three setup SDK zip files, but no where mentioned what version of SDK setup are those? Why such confusions in this Android website for showing just version of SDK setup files? Where i can get exactly Android 1.6 SDK setup download? Could someone point out me clearly?

Is there any special steps that i need to follow to overwrite 1.6 SDK with my existing setup environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got 1.5 setup already, all you need to do is to open Eclipse, goto Window menu > Android SDK and AVD Manager. From there, select "Available Packages" and select the new components you want to download and install from there.

-In the SDK Manager, you may have to select Obsolete(under show) to see 1.6

Answer (score 0):

AIUI the SDK is not versioned. You install the SDK, then install the 1.6-specific components into your development environment. It's all [explained on the website](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/sdk/adding-components.html), quoting:

> Because each version of the Android platform can be installed as an individual component of your SDK, you can customize your development environment to the Android platforms you are targetting. Testing your app on multiple versions of the platform is very important in order to successfully operate on as many devices as possible. Be sure to install each version of the Android platform with which your app is compatible, then test your apps on AVDs that run each platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage any Android SDK from the Android SDK and AVD Manager. [Download it here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

After downloading, unzip the file and run `android.bat`. You will find this inside the `tools` folder. You can then download any version of the Android SDK.

To install/update ADT, check out the guide at Google:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Comment: I tried Eclipse->Window->Android SDK and AVD manager.But it throws error 'parse XML verification failed'. So i downloaded new setup packages as 'detj' said above and installed. But Eclipse doesn't reflect any new installed packages there. I launched Eclipse->Preferences->Android, i didn't find any newly installed packages anywhere. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: check out this link if you want to install Eclipse ADT (Android Development Toolkit) Plugin or just update it in case.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

If you have trouble updating through the Android SDK and AVD Manager, goto Settings and check 'Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...'

Answer (score 0):

The new platform actually includes the older ones. If you install the latest platform, when you create a project you get to choose what platform you want to build against.